# ddply misunderstanding in Wickham's ggplot2 book

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

Page 158 of Wickham's ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis, states this example:

## Select the two smallest diamonds

ddply(diamonds,.(color),subset,order(carat)<=2)

The diamonds data set is huge:

```
> nrow(diamonds)
[1] 53940
```

So I selected a small sample:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
rows=sample(nrow(diamonds),50)
mydiamonds=diamonds[rows,]
```

Then I tried his command on my set.

```
> ddply(mydiamonds,.(color),subset,order(carat)<=2)
   carat     cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1   0.51   Ideal     D     VS2  61.2    55  1882 5.18 5.16 3.16
2   0.58   Ideal     D    VVS1  61.6    60  3154 5.34 5.35 3.29
3   0.70 Premium     E     SI1  59.7    60  2394 5.81 5.79 3.46
4   0.42   Ideal     E     SI2  62.9    56   898 4.80 4.77 3.01
5   0.40 Premium     F     SI1  61.2    58   945 4.74 4.71 2.89
6   0.61 Premium     F     SI1  60.4    56  1359 5.47 5.43 3.29
7   1.52 Premium     G     VS2  62.6    55 12958 7.39 7.28 4.59
8   0.33   Ideal     G    VVS1  61.5    56   868 4.45 4.46 2.74
9   0.71   Ideal     H      IF  62.0    54  3190 5.71 5.75 3.55
10  1.04   Ideal     H     VS2  60.7    56  5805 6.56 6.61 4.00
11  0.70   Ideal     I     SI1  61.8    57  2436 5.67 5.72 3.52
12  0.31   Ideal     I     SI1  62.5    56   537 4.35 4.29 2.70
13  1.35 Premium     J     VS2  60.5    56  6254 7.19 7.12 4.33
14  0.57 Premium     J     VS2  60.2    62  1176 5.40 5.33 3.23
```

Note that the two smallest carat sizes for color H are 0.71 and 1.04. However, consider the following:

```
> subset(mydiamonds,color=="H")
      carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
22060  1.74 Very Good     H     SI2  62.1    59 10086 7.65 7.78 4.79
50726  0.70     Ideal     H     SI1  62.5    56  2294 5.64 5.69 3.54
2458   0.71     Ideal     H      IF  62.0    54  3190 5.71 5.75 3.55
38201  0.44 Very Good     H    VVS1  63.1    56  1016 4.83 4.87 3.06
29333  0.31   Premium     H     VS1  62.6    60   698 4.32 4.30 2.70
17151  1.50      Good     H     SI2  60.8    64  6846 7.27 7.20 4.40
12485  1.07 Very Good     H     VS2  61.5    57  5254 6.57 6.63 4.06
14334  1.04     Ideal     H     VS2  60.7    56  5805 6.56 6.61 4.00
```

Note that this shows I've not selected the two smallest carat diamonds of color H with the ddply command.

So, is this an error in the book or am I misthinking about this question? And what would be the correct use of ddply to select the two smallest diamonds of each color from my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it does not return the smallest carats, but just the first ones in the list.

To get the two smallest carats, you need to take the two first values returned by the order function. the following code seems to work:

```
ddply(mydiamonds,.(color), function(df) df[with(df, order(carat))[1:2], ])

   carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
1   0.40     Ideal     D     VS2  61.6    57   982 4.71 4.77 2.92
2   0.50      Fair     D     SI1  65.7    56  1323 5.01 4.97 3.28
3   0.30     Ideal     E     VS1  62.5    56   778 4.30 4.28 2.68
4   0.32 Very Good     E     SI1  63.3    55   672 4.36 4.33 2.75
5   0.40   Premium     F     SI1  61.2    58   945 4.74 4.71 2.89
6   0.61   Premium     F     SI1  60.4    56  1359 5.47 5.43 3.29
7   0.32     Ideal     G    VVS2  61.6    56   708 4.42 4.44 2.73
8   0.33     Ideal     G    VVS1  61.5    56   868 4.45 4.46 2.74
9   0.31   Premium     H     VS1  62.6    60   698 4.32 4.30 2.70
10  0.44 Very Good     H    VVS1  63.1    56  1016 4.83 4.87 3.06
11  0.31     Ideal     I     SI1  62.5    56   537 4.35 4.29 2.70
12  0.70     Ideal     I     SI1  61.8    57  2436 5.67 5.72 3.52
13  0.57   Premium     J     VS2  60.2    62  1176 5.40 5.33 3.23
14  1.35   Premium     J     VS2  60.5    56  6254 7.19 7.12 4.33
```

Comment: Does it make sense to you David ? @hadley ? Or people ? Any feedback ?